# Best codes for different video formats

Tags: video, video-editor, codec

Is there a list somewhere on the internet to give a basic idea of what codecs are best for different video formats, for example, what codecs are best for MP4, MPEG, FLV etc?

Comment: Codes or CoDecs?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are referring to codecs.

This is to board, there are codecs for different things. That is the point of having different ones. Some parameters can be:

- Best Video Quality
- Lossless compression
- Compression speed
- Decompression speed
- Compatibility
- The resolution, bit depth, etc.

But I must say that in general terms H.264 with audio AAC is the most universally accepted for full HD and mp4 container.

On AVI a good codec that deserves some attention is XVID. which uses a slightly different library than h.264 called x264.

H.265 is the next format intended for higher resolutions, 4K for example, and there it is an open format called x265.

But there is the VP8 and VP9 codecs that are getting traction, and probably will be used more than h.265

There are other codecs meant to be as production codecs, with very little data loss, they are for video editing, like ProRes.

But things are not that simple, because the quality also depends on the configuration of the codec.

---

I would recommend that you forget about the FLV video container.